# Y axis labels from data values

Tags: r

I have a data set that lists the Top 10 web visitors. It has `CustID` and `Visits` columns. I am trying to plot a bar chart. I made the horizontal axis=True. I want the Yaxis labels to list top 10 `custID` from the data - so that for every new dataset the Y axis label value change.

So far, I am using this code:

```
barplot(WebPages$visits, 
        main="Top Visitors", 
        horiz=TRUE,
        col="dark blue")
```

How do I set the Yaxis labels to give the top 10 `custID` from the data?

Comment: Could you give us some data to play with? There are lots of things that could be done with this, and it's easier if we can give you examples.

Comment: Just add the `names.arg=WebPages$CustID` argument to your `barplot(...` call

Comment: SS_11, welcome to StackOverflow.  There's [a great post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) about making a reproducible example.  If you can give us some sample data to play with, it'd be helpful.  Common ways this are done are with the `data` command. Like `data(iris)`, now you can see the `iris` data.frame is in memory.  So if you can find some data and then feed it into your `barplot`, we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the following after calling `barplot` function:

```
axis(2, at = seq(length(WebPages$CustID)), labels = WebPages$CustID)
```

Comment: Thanks! The labels on the Y-axis are not parallel to the x axis.and therefore I am able to see only 5 CustID instead of 10

Comment: Hey SS_11 nobody will be able to get exactly what you are looking for unless you can provide some working example. Use head(df) to let us see what your working with here.